# spark-redshift-connector: combine saving to redshift with a delete query

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-redshift

i would like to update Redshift periodically with **spark-redshift-connector** (scala).
Each update starts with a Delete operation.
(i am performing kind of an **Upsert** to Redshift)

Is there a way i can execute it with the library ?
Can it be with a transaction ?

Any advice will be much appreciated.

thanks,
Eran.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to below example:

```
val min_date=mydf.select(min("actual_ship_date")).rdd.map(line=>line(0)).take(1)
val max_date=mydf.select(max("actual_ship_date")).rdd.map(line=>line(0)).take(1)
val query="delete from semi_sdt.kgd_tsb_shippment where 
actual_ship_date>='"+min_date(0).toString+"' and 
actual_ship_date<='"+max_date(0).toString+"'"
//Write data to RedShift
mydf.coalesce(1).write.
format("com.databricks.spark.redshift").
option("url",redShiftUrl).
option("dbtable","semi_sdt.kgd_tsb_shippment").
option("tempdir",s3dir).
option("forward_spark_s3_credentials",true).
option("preactions",query).
mode("append").
save()
```

Answer (score 1):

it seems that there is an option called "**preactions**" (and "**postactions**") which does the trick.

see the docs:
https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift

Comment: Can you share a working example for reference? Wouldn't I have to anyhow to send the spark data frame to landing area of Redshift in order to do conditional deletes of upsert?  Say: -----------
 ``` delete from test_2 using test_1 where test_2.a=test_1.a and test_2.b=test1.b``` ----- we need to necessarily have test_1 and test_2 in redshift  ---- How would pre-actions help here?